# How to cross-reference another document

Tags: cross-referencing

I am writing a response letter `response.tex` to an academic paper review.
In my response letter,
I want to reference specific pages in the revised paper `paper.tex`,
e.g. "see page 12 of the revised version of the manuscript".
Note that the text appears in `response.tex`
but the reference is to page 12 of the compiled `paper.tex`.

Is it possible to cross-reference page numbers from another LaTeX document?

If not, are there any workarounds
so that I do not have to manually cross-reference page numbers by hand?

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xr , quote

> The pack­age pro­vides a means of cre­at­ing ref­er­ences to la­bels in an­other file (say, oth­er­file.tex) by read­ing that file's aux­il­iary in­for­ma­tion from LaTeX pro­cess­ing (oth­er­file.aux). This is achieved by the \ex­ter­nal­doc­u­ment com­mand, which also per­mits “re­la­belling” all of the ex­ter­nal file with a pre­fix for all of its la­bels.

This actually does work (i use it for supplementary material), please read the package's documentation for further guidance

Answer (score 2):

If I understand it correctly, you want to have the text `page 12` and not the hyperlink to the other document. However, I added information on clickable links at the end.

### Reference text

You could input the `.aux` file from `paper.tex` with

```
\input{paper.aux}
```

and simply use the references in `response.tex` as usual.

### Clickable links with `hyperref`

Using the package `hyperref` in both documents, you can also generate clickable links:
Put

```
\hyperdef{<category>}{<name>}{<text>} %% text and category are optional
```

in `paper.tex` and

```
\hyperref{paper.pdf}{<category>}{<name>}{page~12}
```

in `response.tex`.