# How to create a page reference to another separate document in ConTeXt?

Tags: cross-referencing, context

My question is similar to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/256156/how-to-cross-reference-another-document), but for ConTeXt.

I have multiple documents, that are to be bundled as a set (e.g. textbook, workbook, teachers' guide). I frequently need to make a cross-reference to another item, e.g. the workbook might say "Refer to Article 3 on p. 1 of the textbook."

Is there a way to make such cross-references?
s
Hyperlinking is not needed.

Answer (score 4):

You can do that with `\useexternaldocument` as described in the [wiki](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/References):

```
% textbook.tex

\starttext

\startchapter[title=Knuth,reference=knuth]
  \input knuth
\stopchapter

\stoptext
```

[image]

```
% workbook.tex

\setupinteraction
  [state=start]

\useexternaldocument
  [tb][textbook][Textbook]

\setupinteraction
  [state=start,
   color=darkgreen]

\starttext

See Knuth on \at{page}[tb::knuth] of the \from[tb].

\stoptext
```

[image]

Comment: You can refer to the other document without `\useexternaldocument` when you put the name of the other document before `::` in the reference (i.e. `\at{page}[textbook::knuth]`. Setting a different name for the document with `\useexternaldocument` is still recommended.

Comment: Thanks! That’s good to know